# ERC20 token with expiration date

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask

I would like to create a ERC20 token with an expiration date to represent for example a ticket or a gift card. 
I've created a contract which overrides the open-zeppelin ERC20 contract methods.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin- solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";  
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Mintable.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";


/**  
* @title EventToken is a basic ERC20 Token  
*/  
contract EventToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed, ERC20Mintable, ERC20Burnable {

uint256 ticketExpiryDateTimestamp;

constructor(
    uint256 _initialSupply,
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    uint8 _decimals,
    uint256 _ticketExpiryDateTimestamp
    )  
        ERC20Detailed(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
        ERC20Mintable()
        ERC20Burnable()
        ERC20()
        public
{
    mint(msg.sender, _initialSupply);
    ticketExpiryDateTimestamp = _ticketExpiryDateTimestamp;
}

function totalSupply() public view returns(uint256) {
    if(now > ticketExpiryDateTimestamp) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return ERC20.totalSupply();
    }
}

function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    if(now > ticketExpiryDateTimestamp) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return ERC20.balanceOf(owner);
    }
}

function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns(uint256) {
    if(now > ticketExpiryDateTimestamp) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return ERC20.allowance(owner, spender);
    }
}

function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns(bool) {
    if(now > ticketExpiryDateTimestamp) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return ERC20.transfer(to, value);
    }
}

function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    if(now > ticketExpiryDateTimestamp) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return ERC20.approve(spender, value);
    }
}

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns(bool) {
    if(now > ticketExpiryDateTimestamp) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return ERC20.transferFrom(from, to, value);
    }
}
}
```

It's how I did the override of the ERC20 standard.
It's the way how I deploy it:

```
var EventToken = artifacts.require("./EventToken.sol");

const tokenCode = "TCK";
const tokenFullName = "TicketToken";
const initialSupply = "100";
const decimals = "0";
const epochTimeSeconds = Date.now() / 100;
const expireAfterSeconds = 60 * 2;
const expiryDate = epochTimeSeconds + expireAfterSeconds;

module.exports = function(deployer) {
 deployer.deploy(
 EventToken,
 initialSupply,
 tokenFullName,
 tokenCode,
 decimals,
 expiryDate
 );
};
```

After the deployment I see my tokens on metamask but after two minutes they are still there. 
I would like to know how to implement the logic of an expiration of an ERC20 token or how to fix my code to do so.
Thanks in advantage

Comment: I think you want `Date.now() / 1000`.

Comment: I would be suspicious of the `ticketExpiryDateTimeStamp` computed outside. Consider passing in `uint durationInSeconds` and then setting `ticketExpiryDateTimeStamp = now + durationInSeconds;` Also keep in mind the timeStamp isn't perfect.

Comment: Thank you Rob Hitchens, when I generate the expiration date inside the contract it works thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `block.timestamp` to get the current time. When a user tries to transfer tokens check if it is expired or not.

```
require(block.timestamp < ticketExpiryDateTimestamp);
```

For custom expiration store ticketExpiryDateTimestamp for each user in a mapping.